# Azure App Service - alerting for HTTP errors more than X% of total requests

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to setup alert based on percentage of Http Errors in all Requests, e.g. - *"Notify me, when more than 0.5% of all requests end up with Http Error."*

When I look at App Service [alerting capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-monitor#cpu-time-vs-cpu-percentage), I can setup alerts to let me know when number of Http Errors is higher than X, I can also setup alerts to let me know when total number of Requests is higher than Y. But nothing that would compare those two numbers.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no build-in feature for you to achieve this purpose. But you could write your code for retrieving the metrics and send the alert notification by yourself. I assumed that you could leverage [Azure Monitor REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt743622.aspx) for getting metrics from [Microsoft.Web/sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftwebsites-excluding-functions) as follows:

```
Get https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroupName}/providers/${resourceProviderNamespace}/${resourceType}/${resourceName}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?$filter=(name.value eq 'Requests' or name.value eq 'http401' or name.value eq 'http403') and startTime eq 2017-07-11T12:30:00Z and endTime eq 2017-07-11T12:31:00Z&api-version=2016-06-01
```

[image]

For more details, you could refer to [Azure Monitoring REST API Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough).

Additionally, you could leverage [Web Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) for running your programs or scripts periodically to retrieve your expected metrics and write your logic code for sending alert notification.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ApplicationInsights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/)? I think it can fulfill your requirement.

Below image is alert rules that ApplicationInsights gives. You can use Exception rate, Server exceptions, or Failed request. Basically, it already configured abnormal status alert out of the box and will send email notification, so called *Smart Detection*.

[image]

Comment: Am I correct thinking, thank this assumes that Application Insight SDK is added to the build process and the app is instrumented?

Comment: @LechMigdal it works without installing sdk also. But it works more precisely if you add library to your webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe this is possible today.